# want command lines .bat to search in all files in c:\ and if exist virus.bat deleted and do some code ELSE do another

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, dos

want command lines .bat to search in all files in c:\ and if exist virus.bat

```
 Del  virus.bat
set /a viruses=%viruses%+1
cls
echo Yoy are infected! The infected files ware deleted  !!
pause
goto Start
```

ELSE

```
 cls
echo Your computer is clean!
pause
goto Start
```

i look in many web sites and got nothing ! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`del /?` could help.  Then, use

```
del /F /S c:\virus.bat &echo Your computer is clean!
pause
goto Start
```

Output examples (another drive):

```
==>del /F /S d:\virus.bat &echo Your computer is clean!
Deleted file - d:\bat\virus.bat
Deleted file - d:\temp\virus.bat
Your computer is clean!

==>del /F /S d:\virus.bat &echo Your computer is clean!
Could Not Find d:\virus.bat
Your computer is clean!

==>
```

(In respond to your comment). The effect is the same: your computer could be clean as soon as infected files were deleted... :) However, if you do insist on exact wording, start with

```
set "virusfound="
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /B /S "c:\virus.bat"') do (
   set "virusfound=%%G"
   del /F "%%~G"
)
if defined virusfound (
    echo virus found, did an attempt to delete it
) else (
    echo virus not found
)
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Comment: may u not catch my point ! .. if not found echo Your computer is clean! if f found it del it and echo file deleted